# Select second to nth values in list R

Tags: r, string, list, vector, extract

I have a list with vectors that contain strings, say it is called x:

```
b <- c("aaaaaa", "bbbb")
c <- c("aaaaaaaa", "bbbbbb", "cccccc")
d <- c("aaaaa", "bbbbb", "ccccc")
e <- c("aaaaa", "bbbbb", "cccccc", "ddddddd")
x <- list(b,c,d,e)
```

I would like to extract the range between the second value and beyond, from all the vectors in the list x. Say, the desired output would be a list with the second string in b, the second and third string from c, the second and third string in d and the second, third and fourth string in e.

I know that with:

```
lapply(x, '[[', 2)
```

I can extract the second value from each vector in the list, but I would like to obtain from the second till the end of the vector.

How could I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use direct indexing we can just modify your code to use single bracket indexing (because double bracket only allows for grabbing a single element but single bracket allows for multiple) and a negative index which means "grab all the elements *except* the one I specify".

```
lapply(x, "[", -1)
```

Alternatively you can use the `tail` function with the argument of "-1"

```
> b <- c("aaaaaa", "bbbb")
> c <- c("aaaaaaaa", "bbbbbb", "cccccc")
> d <- c("aaaaa", "bbbbb", "ccccc")
> e <- c("aaaaa", "bbbbb", "cccccc", "ddddddd")
> x <- list(b,c,d,e)
> lapply(x, tail, -1)
[[1]]
[1] "bbbb"

[[2]]
[1] "bbbbbb" "cccccc"

[[3]]
[1] "bbbbb" "ccccc"

[[4]]
[1] "bbbbb"   "cccccc"  "ddddddd"
```

Comment: Holy shit, I have been half an hour thinking about this... Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

We can simply do that by removing the first element from vector `x[-1]`

```
 b <- c("aaaaaa", "bbbb")
 c <- c("aaaaaaaa", "bbbbbb", "cccccc")
 d <- c("aaaaa", "bbbbb", "ccccc")
 e <- c("aaaaa", "bbbbb", "cccccc", "ddddddd")
 x <- list(b,c,d,e)
 lapply(x, function(x){x[-1]})
 [[1]]
 [1] "bbbb"

 [[2]]
 [1] "bbbbbb" "cccccc"

 [[3]]
 [1] "bbbbb" "ccccc"

 [[4]]
 [1] "bbbbb"   "cccccc"  "ddddddd"
```